Do Web Applications Follow Single Tier Architecture?
I have been studying about Single-Tier and Multi-Tier Architecture.
i want to know that do web applications follow Single-Tier Architecture or not?
I have searched on Internet about Single-Tier Architecture, according to my understanding Applications which run on single user machine and all of its data resides on same machine. Such Applications don't require to request from external machine to fetch the Data, like we use MS Word, all of it's reside on system.
But In Web Applications, this can not be the case because in Web Applications we need to request Data from external/ remote server due to client-server architecture.
So Do Web Applications Follw Single-Tier Architecture?
